# add and maintain sequence continuity across files using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am looking for help to insert a sequence number column in a file.

I have a file generated everyday with data like:

899831,login

819823,test

...

I need to add a sequence number column to this, so that the data comes out as:

1,899831,login

2,819823,test

... and so on.

But that's not it. The next day when a new file is generated, the continuity of the sequence should be maintained from the previous day file.

For e.g. if the last line of the previous day file was:

2,819823,test

then my current day file sequence number should start with 3.

Can this be achieved with shell script ? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it can be achieved with a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some initial thoughts. Depending on how/where these files are stored you can use `ls` or `find` to find the latest file. If none is found then you know you have to start your numbering at 1. If a file is found, a combination of `tail` and/or `sed` will make it easy to find the last sequence number used. Adding the sequence number column is almost trivial with `awk`.